# How do I perform a HAVING on a func.count?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my code:

```
    charge_count = func.count(ChargeLog).label('charge_count')
    q = (session.query(PaymentProfile, charge_count)
         .outerjoin(ChargeLog, ChargeLog.profile_id == PaymentProfile._id)
         .filter(PaymentProfile.date_expiry_utc >= datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=(TOTAL_TIMES_TO_CHARGE - charging_attempt_0idx)))
         .filter(PaymentProfile.status == payments.ProfileStatus.ACTIVE)
         .filter(ChargeLog.date_created_utc > PaymentProfile.date_charged_utc)
         .group_by(PaymentProfile)
         .having(charge_count == charging_attempt_0idx))
```

However, I'm getting an error of `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'DeclarativeMeta'`.

Specifically:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'DeclarativeMeta' [SQL: 'SELECT payment_profile._id AS payment_profile__id, payment_profile.sb_org_id AS payment_profile_sb_org_id, payment_profile.plan_id AS payment_profile_plan_id, payment_profile.status AS payment_profile_status, payment_profile.date_created_utc AS payment_profile_date_created_utc, payment_profile.date_updated_utc AS payment_profile_date_updated_utc, payment_profile.date_charged_utc AS payment_profile_date_charged_utc, payment_profile.date_expiry_utc AS payment_profile_date_expiry_utc, payment_profile.payment_method_id AS payment_profile_payment_method_id, count(%(param_1)s) AS charge_count \nFROM payment_profile LEFT OUTER JOIN charge_log ON charge_log.profile_id = payment_profile._id \nWHERE payment_profile.date_expiry_utc >= %(date_expiry_utc_1)s AND payment_profile.status = %(status_1)s AND charge_log.date_created_utc > payment_profile.date_charged_utc GROUP BY payment_profile._id, payment_profile.sb_org_id, payment_profile.plan_id, payment_profile.status, payment_profile.date_created_utc, payment_profile.date_updated_utc, payment_profile.date_charged_utc, payment_profile.date_expiry_utc, payment_profile.payment_method_id \nHAVING count(%(param_1)s) = %(param_2)s'] [parameters: {'date_expiry_utc_1': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 14, 9, 2, 11, 353027), 'param_1': , 'status_1': 'active', 'param_2': 0}]

And I attribute it to `'param_1': <class 'sb_base.model.ChargeLog'>`, by which `charge_count` is not translating into a label to be parsed in the `having` condition.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a column from the `ChargeLog` table, not the table mapping object itself. Use the primary key:

```
# assumption: ChargeLog.id is the primary key
charge_count = func.count(ChargeLog.id).label('charge_count')
```

This inserts the same expression in both the `SELECT` columns and the `HAVING` clause; you can't normally use labels in `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT
  -- more columns
  count(charge_log.id) AS charge_count
-- FROM, OUTER JOIN, WHERE, GROUP_BY
HAVING count(charge_log.id)
```